# Going from a specific class up the tree to Object and getting their methods(without them being written more than once)

Tags: java, class, class-hierarchy

So I have a problem.My assingment untill tommorw is to make a java program,that gets a class,then writes its Name and methods,Then gets the one that it implements,does the same and continues up to Object.The problem is I have to make it so the methods don't repeat themselves.(Only the class that adds the method should print it out,the implementation of that class should no longer have it.)
I made it so it prints everything only once,but it prints it out very strangely. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = new JRadioButton();
    Class cl;
    HashSet methodsnames = new HashSet();

    for (cl = o.getClass(); cl != null; cl = cl.getSuperclass()) {
       HashSet al = new HashSet();
       System.out.println(cl.getName()+ " - ");
       for (Method m : cl.getMethods()){
           boolean added = methodsnames.add(m.getName());
           if(added){
           al.add(m.getName());}
        }
       al.forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("=============================");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the output ?

Comment: How does your output look and how should it look like?

Comment: there is no need to create added inside the loop

Comment: All of it was printed out under JRadioButton(which gives sense because all the methods are there giving that it is an implementaion) but changing to declared solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getDeclaredMethods` instead `getMethods`:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class main
{
    public static void main(String ...args) {
        Object o = new JRadioButton();
        Class cl;
        HashSet methodsnames = new HashSet();

        for (cl = o.getClass(); cl != null; cl = cl.getSuperclass()) {
           HashSet al = new HashSet();
           System.out.println(cl.getName()+ " - ");
           for (Method m : cl.getDeclaredMethods()){
               boolean added = methodsnames.add(m.getName());
               if(added){
                   al.add(m.getName());
               }
           }
           al.forEach(System.out::println);

           System.out.println("=============================");
        }
    }
}
```

Check this code runing on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/vJxkgr).

Answer (score 2):

With `Class#getMethods` you get all public methods of the class - even the public methods provided by its super-class.

I think you want to print the method only if the class also provides the implementation so you need to check the declaring class: `m.getDeclaringClass().equals(cl)`

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:
    m.getDeclaringClass().equals(cl)